# Jquery UI Tooltip Mouse to fast generates Errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

I am generating a Calendar with PHP and I want to have tooltip for each day with data collected from Ajax request (via jQuery).

I have done that, but I am getting strange error when I am trying to navigate too fast with mouse cursor. Some Tooltips are stucked. Any idea how to correct that?

Here is my code for `DIV` for each day:

```
<div style="-moz-border-radius:8px; border-radius: 8px;" 
   class="pusty" id="dzien_'.$day.'"  
   onclick="idz_do_dnia('.$day.','.$miesiac.','.$rok.','.$gildia[id_gildi].')" 
   onmouseover="zaznacz('.$day.','.$data_s.','.$data_k.','.$gildia[id_gildi].')" 
   onmouseout="odznacz('.$day.')" > 
   &nbsp; 
</div>
```

and here is 2 javascript functions to show tooltim (named: zaznacz) and to hide them (named: odznacz)

```
function zaznacz(id,data_s,data_k,gildia)
{
    jQuery("#dzien_"+id).removeClass("pusty");
    jQuery("#dzien_"+id).addClass("zaznaczony");

    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url: '/raidplanner_mini.php?data_s='+data_s+'&data_k='+data_k+'&gildia='+gildia,
        success:function(data)
        {
            if (!jQuery("#dzien_"+id).hasClass("tooledUp"))
            {
                jQuery("#dzien_"+id).tooltip(
                {
                    content: data,
                    show: false,
                    tooltipClass: "tooltip",
                    hide: false,
                    track: false,
                 }); 
                jQuery("#dzien_"+id).tooltip("open");
                jQuery("#dzien_"+id).addClass("tooledUp"); 
            }
            //else
          //jQuery("#dzien_"+id).tooltip().show();
        }   
    });
}
function odznacz(id)
{
    jQuery("#dzien_"+id).removeClass("zaznaczony");
    jQuery("#dzien_"+id).addClass("pusty");
}
```

any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

That bug is being tracked here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8740

I've used the following workaround in my chrome extension. I added a handler for open in the jQueryUI tooltip initialization that goes as follows:

```
    open: function() {
        $(this).one('mouseout.wpcustom', function() {

            $(this)
                .off('mouseout.wpcustom')
                .tooltip('disable')
                .tooltip('enable');
        });
    }
```

This forces the tooltip to close (using `.tooltip('disable')`) on any mouseout event.
See the full code here: https://github.com/jncornett/wiki-preview/blob/master/src/js/inject.js